# How to send Mass email using Visualforce Template to Contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template, class

I need to send Mass email to contacts with related Lead data. I have a Visualforce email template that has the related Lead information. Is there any way to write a batch class to send out an email to all contacts on a particular time. 
An email should not be sent to contact if it does not have any related Lead data.
Need help ASAP, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a time-based workflow that fires upon creation.  The criteria should be lead status = not contacted.  Add a time-dependent workflow that sends an email alert 3 days after creating date.